How do I mitigate the HTTP Parameter Pollution vulnerability for the Captcha.aspx in the ASP.NET Web Forms application
We recently scanned our web application using the Tenable web app scanning tool, and that tool detected a medium vulnerability called HTTP Parameter Pollution
That vulnerability detected a specific section within our web application, the Captcha.aspx
We don't use that component explicitly. The Captcha.aspx is a third party tool provided by Google. The only section where we mention the Captcha.aspx is the Web.config
Also we have this code in the Captcha control
protected override void Render(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    writer.Write("<Div><Table>");            
    writer.Write("<tr><td><img src=\"CaptchaImage.aspx?guid=" + _captcha.UniqueID + "\"></td></tr>");
    writer.Write("<tr><td><input style='width: 120px;' name=\"" + this.UniqueID + "\" type=text></td></tr>");
    writer.Write("</Table></Div>");
}

Can some one please suggest on how to mitigate that vulnerability

The problem is here: img src=\"CaptchaImage.aspx?guid=" + _captcha.UniqueID.   It appears CapthcaImage.aspx accepts a parameter called guid.  A user could supply any value they want to that guid parameter. There are a lot of tutorials out there on how to mitigate HPP attack.

This question is similar to: HTTP Parameter Pollution. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. While your server side language is not PHP, the answer for how to mitigate HPP attack is not specific to server side language.

Here is what worked for me
    protected override void Render(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        if (IsValidCaptcha(_captcha.UniqueID))
        {
            writer.Write("<Div><Table>");
            writer.Write("<tr><td><img src=\"CaptchaImage.aspx?guid=" + _captcha.UniqueID + "\"></td></tr>");
            writer.Write("<tr><td><input style='width: 120px;' name=\"" + this.UniqueID + "\" type=text></td></tr>");
            writer.Write("</Table></Div>");
        }
    }

    private bool IsValidCaptcha(string captchaValue)
    {
        // Implement your validation logic (length, format, etc.)
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(captchaValue) && captchaValue.Length <= 50;
    }

